# Meijer's G function implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica

I need the Meijer's G function in a MATLAB code. Since no implementation of this function exists in MATLAB, I tried to code the function based on the integral representation given in http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/07/01/.

My code is inspired from the code given in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05445v1.pdf.

```
function out = Meijer_G(an, ap, bm, bq, z)
%***** Integrand definition *****
F = @(s)(GammaProd(bm,s).*GammaProd(1-an,-s).*(z.^(-s)))./(GammaProd(ap,s).*GammaProd(1-bq,-s));

%***** Contour definition *****
Sups = min(bm);
Infs = -max(1-an); % cs
cs = (Sups + Infs)/2;% s between Sups and Infs
W = 50; % W
%***** Bivariate Meijer G *****
out = real((1/(2*pi*1i))*quadv(@(s) F(s),cs-1i*W,cs+1i*W)); 

function output = GammaProd(p,z)
[pp, zz] = meshgrid(p,z);
if (isempty(p)) 
  output = ones(size(z));
else
  output = reshape(prod(gammac(pp+zz),2),size(z));
end
end
end;
```

The gammac function here is the complex gamma, available in
% www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3572-gamma.

The problem is that when I compare my code using numerical values to the Meijer's G function given in Mathematica, there is a difference in certain cases. I was wondering if you could help fix the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not have the Symbolic Toolbox for Matlab? If you do, then you can use MuPAD's [`meijerG`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/meijerg.html). MuPAD functions can be called from Matlab with the [methods described here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html). Or try this [this File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31490-meijerg).

Comment: I did try to call MuPAD's `meijerG` function but again for certain parameters, I don't get the same values.

Comment: You should probably include precise examples of discrepancy. The trouble might be  more of a mathematical nature (hidden simplifications, convention about branch points and integration contours for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Starting R2017b, meijerG is available directly in MATLAB. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/meijerg.html. You need Symbolic Math Toolbox.